# How to write mathematical equations above and below double harpoons in chemical equations?

Tags: math-mode, chemmacros

I'm trying to write a chemical equation with k_f and k_b (in math mode) above and below a double harpoon, respectively. I wrote the following code, which uses the *chemmacros* package:

```latex
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s=1}^{N_s}\nu'_s \ch{X}_s  \ch{<=>[$k_f$][$k_b$]}   \sum_{s=1}^{N_s}\nu''_s \ch{X}_s 
\label{eq:chemical_reaction_f_b}
\end{equation}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can see, the f and b in the two k letters aren't in subscript as desired. How can I correct this?

Comment: Did any errors get reported in the log?  Specifically regarding math mode?

Comment: add blank spaces `\ch{<=>[ $k_f$ ][ $k_b$ ]}`

Comment: @polyn it indeed also works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The processing of the arrow arguments somehow interferes with math mode. A workaround is to define two small macros that hide the content long enough to be processed normally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\def\kf{k_f}
\def\kb{k_b}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s=1}^{N_s}\nu'_s \ch{X}_s  \ch{<=>[$\kf$][$\kb$]}   \sum_{s=1}^{N_s}\nu''_s \ch{X}_s 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's of course not ideal but if you don't need a lot of different variable-subscript combinations then it may be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, this expression isn't an equation; rather, it's a *reaction* (a definition of a generic elementary reaction in chemical kinetics, to be precise). I think using labeled `reaction` environment from `chemmacros`'s `reactions` module suits this case much better: this way one can also address it later both in text and in the list of reactions.

As for the troubles with math inside the chemical environment, [`chemformula`'s manual](http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula_en.pdf#page=22) covers this case well (this has also been mentioned by [polyn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/186244/polyn) in the comments):

> ### 8.2. Math
>
> If you especially want to input math you just enclose it with `$ $`. This output is different from the escaped text as it is followed by a space. The reasoning behind this is that I assume math will mostly be used to replace stoichiometric factors.
>
> `\ch{ $⟨escaped math⟩$ }`
>   One of two possibilities to escape `chemformula`’s parsing into math mode.
>
> `\ch{ \(⟨escaped math⟩\) }`
>   The second of two possibilities to escape `chemformula`’s parsing into math mode.

Additionally, I would use roman typeface for the textual subscripts instead of italics, and also denote forward and reverse rates with more common notations used in kinetics: k_fwd and k_rev instead of k_f and k_b, correspondingly. The subscript "f", for instance, is ambiguous and denotes "formation" or "fusion" in physical chemistry.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules=all}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
    $\sum_{s=1}^{N\sb{s}}\nu'_s$ X_{$s$} 
    <=>[ $k_\mathrm{fwd}$ ][ $k_\mathrm{rev}$ ]
    $\sum_{s=1}^{N\sb{s}}\nu''_s$ X_{$s$}
    "\label{rxn:generic-kinetic-model}"
\end{reaction}

Reaction \ref{rxn:generic-kinetic-model} is elementary.

\listofreactions

\end{document}
```